# How to detect the row of the cell which has been touched

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, push, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a `UITableViewController`, and of course a `UITableView` cell in my application. And I have a push segue(to another `UIViewController`) for the cell. How to detect the row of the cell which has been touched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Selected row is %d",[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check the table rows state and you put your instructions in the cellValueChanged block